# Google App Engine: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

Tags: python, google-maps, google-app-engine, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on an application which requires calculating the distance between two locations that were given as input by the user. I'm using Google Map's Distance Matrix API for this purpose. Here's the code:

```
class MainPage(Handler):
    def get(self):
        self.render('map.html')
    def post(self):
        addr1 = self.request.get("addr1")
        addr2 = self.request.get("addr2")
        url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=' + addr1 + '&destinations=' + addr2 + '&mode=driving&sensor=false'
        link = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
        self.response.write(link)
```

map.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Fare Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method = "post">
        Source<input type = 'text' name = "addr1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        Destination<input type = 'text' name = "addr2">
        <br><br>
        <input type = "submit" value = "Calculate Fare">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

map.html contains a basic HTML form with input for the source and destination addresses. However, when I run this application, I get a HTTP Error 400: Bad Request. What's happening?

Comment: Are you getting the error on `get` or `post`?

Comment: Getting the error on the 'post'

Comment: Can you give an example of `addr1` or `addr2`?

Comment: addr1 = 'Gorai 3'...addr2 = 'Thakur college'. Both work well when I tested on the link provided by the Google Maps API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variables need to be urlencoded for the API request.

```
...    
url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=' + urllib.quote_plus(addr1) + '&destinations=' + urllib.quote_plus(addr2) + '&mode=driving&sensor=false'
...
```

You can read more about `.quote_plus` [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote_plus).

Comment: I prefer to build a dict of params and call urllib.urlencode on it.

Comment: @marcadian - I agree.